# java.Nullpointer when read csv file performance test jmeter

Tags: performance, csv, testing, nullpointerexception, jmeter

I have issue, which is relate to read csv file. When i run jmx file with gui, everything is ok, but when run with non-gui always show error java.lang.Nullpointer exception.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to "See the log file for details"? The file is called `jmeter.log` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation or in the folder where you launch JMeter from (if it differs from the above)

You can try troubleshooting the issue yourself by comparing JMeter log files from GUI and from non-GUI execution. Another suggestion is using full path to the CSV file instead of the relative one.

References:

- [JMeter Hints and Tips: Enabling debug logging](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)